# HowTo: Zend_Form processing via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, zend-framework, zend-form

i'm digging more and more into Zend_Framework, but finding good resources isn't all too easy, as a lot is coming from older versions. So i'm hoping to find some input from here.

I'm looking for **the right way** to ajaxify my Zend_Forms. Sometimes i want a form to be called via ajax and then obviously process it via ajax, too. Calling the ajax form is working fine, but im struggling a little bit with the processing.

Currently my action looks like this:

```
// asset/add
public function addAction() {
  $form = new Application_Form_Asset();
  if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    if($form->isValid($this->_getAllParams())) {
      // Process to database using either Flashmessenger and redirector or view->message for success output
    }
  }
  $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

Now i don't really understand by how far i need to change this code. Basically what i want to achieve is the following:

1. Call the form via ajax (that i can do, ajaxContext and such, no problem)
2. Process the form via ajax, too (working, too, jQuery, but the processing result is not what i want
3. The result should be a json from the object stored to the database

And the connection from point 2-3 is exactly where i have my problems finding resources for on the internet.

**Guessed Solution**: My guess is, that i need to rearrange my Controllers and Form-handling in a way that i don't handle everything inside `addAction()` but to have this and `processaddAction()` where addActions only task is to display the form and processadd does the validation and insertion to the database. But even with this model i don't really see how i can do the json output.

I'm simply stuck a little in my thought. Some "Zendwords" i should look up would probably be enough for me to find out what i want to achieve, but if someone wants to give me a working example, i wouldn't say no ;)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this suits exactly your needs, but the following tutorial is quite clear:

http://www.zendcasts.com/ajaxify-your-zend_form-validation-with-jquery/2010/04/

I'm using the ideas contained there to validate the fields through Ajax (as you say, using a different `validateAction`), both interactively (when they lose the focus in the browser) and before submitting.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Yeah, that pretty much goes hand in hand with my guessed solution. Thanks for the link, i've watched it couple of weeks ago and am familiar with it. I don't know why, but i just hoped there's a more... "inbuilt method" to do this kind of thing, apart from creating an own action. But i guess this is what it comes down to :P

Answer (score 1):

I did it by adding a button (not submit type) and a jquery click event on that button.
Validation was hadeled by validation plugin for jquery.

1. The Ajax call will point to the controller/action (processaddAction) that will proccess the data.
2. Then get data and json_encode it (return $json)

   public function processaddAction(){
    //do the proccessing
    return json_encode($data);
   }
3. Your Ajax success function will catch the json

   $.ajax({
      url: "/controller/processaddAction",
      type: 'POST',
      data: 'data='+ [POST DATA],
      async: false,
      success: function(theJson){

   }
   });

The form was only generated by Zend-FW.